# Most efficient way to resolve the 'IndexError: list index out of range' error in Python?

Tags: python, error-handling

When running a Python script, I am encountering an 'IndexError: list index out of range' error. This error occurs when trying to access an index in a list that is outside the range of valid indices.

For example, consider the following code:

```py
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(numbers[10])
```

In this code, the list numbers has 5 elements, so the highest index available is 4. However, the code tries to access the 10th index, which is out of range, resulting in the IndexError: list index out of range error.

What is the most efficient way to resolve this error and ensure that I am only accessing indices within the range of the list?

Comment: Simply delete that second line of code.

Answer (score 2):

If by solving, you mean, capping index, then this is a simple way to do it :

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(numbers[min(10, len(numbers) - 1)])
```